# Spring saml - how remember request parameter when initiate login on SP, and procesing them after IdP response

Tags: openssl, saml, spring-saml

I want remember url request parameter from first request of my site (SP) and use them after response from IdP.

I'm using spring-saml extension and think about relayState attribute but can't find example how build it with parameters from request.

I need that for redirect user after sso authentication process to target page (module of application) depends on what was in first request.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Spring SAML sample application behaves like this out of the box. When user hits a page which is protected by Spring Security and requires authentication system:

- remembers parameters which were used to invoke the page (done automatically inside Spring Security using `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and `HttpSessionRequestCache`) by storing the information into the HTTP session
- invokes Spring SAML's entry point (`SAMLEntryPoint` class) which redirects user to the IDP, possible after IDP selection
- user authenticates at IDP and is redirected back to your application
- Spring SAML verifies the response and invokes AuthenticationSuccessHandler, which (in the sample application) is of type `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`
- the success handler checks whether there's a stored request (put there in the first step) and if so it makes user's browser to open the remembered page with the same set of parameters as initially
- the security check should now pass, provided the authenticated user is authorized to access the page

You could of course implement this using relay state as you intended. The correct way to set relay state is by extending `SAMLEntryPoint`, overriding method `getProfileOptions` and returning your desired relay state in the returned `WebSSOProfileOptions` object.

You can then change the `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` to `org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler` which make redirect to the URL returned from the relay state after successful authentication.

Comment: Great! I need exacly this sentence: "The correct way to set relay state is by extending SAMLEntryPoint, overriding method getProfileOptions and returning your desired relay state in the returned WebSSOProfileOptions object." Thanks a lot.

Comment: relayState was a nice way to pass context between the authentication server and client. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is there a way to support both simultaneously?  I would want the `SavedRequestAware...` behavior for SP-initiated, but `SAMLRelayState....` for IdP-initiated.

Comment: In response to my own comment: `SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler` extends `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.  For SP-initiated, RelayState is not supplied and it defaults to redirecting to the original request for the protected page.  For IdP initiated, user is redirected to the target deep link in the RelayState.

Comment: Being aware that this is a very old question: How would you configure handling of request parameters if using multi tenancy, i.e. an alias? 
When doing it the default way, you would just go to any URL protected by Spring Security, the SAML package will store away the original URL, go to disco and do the rest of SSO flow. However, when using alias, I've assumed that you just go /saml/login/alias/otherLogin. That works, but it seems it bypasses the storage of the request. I.e., doing /saml/login/alias/otherLogin/?foo=bar does not result in going to ?foo=bar after successful logon. Any tips?