# Add request parameter to SAML request using Spring Security SAML 2

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-saml2

**Expected Behavior**
I intend to add a request parameter when initiating login on the Service Provider (SP) and process it after receiving the Identity Provider (IdP) response.

<!--- Tell us how it should work -->

**Current Behavior**
My application currently utilizes the approach described in this Stack Overflow topic: [[Stack Overflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012718/spring-saml-how-remember-request-parameter-when-initiate-login-on-sp-and-proc)]. I have this endpoint in my application:

```java
    @GetMapping("/saml/{companySlug}/course/{courseCode}")
    public String courseRedirect(@PathVariable("companySlug") String companySlug, @PathVariable("courseCode") String courseCode) {
        Company company = companyRepository.findSAMLBySlug(companySlug).orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new);
        return String.format("redirect:/saml/login?idp=%s&urlAfterLogin=%s/sso?courseCode=%s", company.getIdpUrl(), "http://localhost:8080/", courseCode);
    }
```

and a SAMLEntryPoint extension with `request.getParameter("urlAfterLogin")`. However, when attempting to recreate the same behavior with with a new implementation of `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, even with additions to `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, it was not successful. This includes the following code snippet:

```java
http
.exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
.authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint()))
```

- There is no setRelayStateResolver(this::resolveCustomRelayState) in OpenSaml4AuthenticationRequestResolver.
- resolve() method of Interface Saml2AuthenticationRequestResolver has return type T extends AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest and AbstractSaml2AuthenticationRequest is not eligible for inheritance outside package has default scope on constructor.

I tried to follow the first suggestion in this issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11065

And make my Saml2AuthenticationRequestRepository implementation